# Why is my Kendo Chart not being rendered?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz

I have decided that the MVC wrappers that come with Kendo in some cases are just too restrictive and difficult to follow.  Telerik added the ability to call a Javascript function to calculate the colour of a point on a chart.  However I cannot find any example of the syntax of this for MVC

So I have decided to use the wrappers to help generate my javascript and to use this in my cshtml files

However, when I do this my chart is not rendered?

```
<div id="chartContainer" class="chartContainer">

    <script>
        function CreateChart() {
            $("#kendoChart").kendoChart({
                "chartArea": {
                    "border": {
                        "width": 1,
                        "dashType": "solid",
                        "color": "#cdcdcd"
                    }
                },
                "plotArea": {
                    "margin": {
                        "top": 0,
                        "right": 0,
                        "bottom": 0,
                        "left": 0
                    }
                },
                "legend": {
                    "visible": false
                },
                "series": [{
                    "name": "Consumption",
                    "type": "column",
                    "field": "Consumption",
                    "categoryField": "PeriodDateTime"
                }],
                "categoryAxis": [{
                    "labels": {
                        "format": "dd/MM/yy",
                        "rotation": -90,
                        "step": 48
                    },
                    "majorGridLines": {
                        "visible": false
                    },
                    "type": "date",
                    "baseUnit": "minutes",
                    "baseUnitStep": 30
                }],
                "valueAxis": [{
                    "labels": {
                        "format": "{0:N0}"
                    },
                    "line": {
                        "visible": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Consumption kWh"
                    }
                }],
                "transitions": false,
                "seriesColors": ["green"],
                "tooltip": {
                    "format": "{0:N0}",
                    "visible": true
                },
                "autoBind": false
            });
        }

        CreateChart();
    </script>


</div>
```

However, this does not render?

I have also tried calling CreateChart from document.ready but no luck there either

Please see the screenshot below [image: screenshot]

I have also tried to locate the containing div and calling appendChild but I get an error stating there is no method appendChild?

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  This must be something stupidly obvious but I cant see it!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You do not have dataSource in your chart construction object. You have to specify it:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
         data: [
            { price: 10 },
            { price: 20 }
        ]
    }
    ...
});
```

or enter series explicitly:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    series: [{
        name: "India",
        data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855]
    },{
        name: "World",
        data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, 2.727]
    }],
    ...
});
```

You can find more info about chart dataSource here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-dataSource.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that when I get to the office it will just have to be a temporary datasource in the markup I guess because I replace it when a user selects a row in the grid